# Deleting a file in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I want to delete a file, and sometimes I can, sometimes I don't. I'm doing this:

```
String filePath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\temp.xml";
File f = new File(filePath);
if (f.exists())
{
  if(f.delete())
     System.out.println("deleted");
  else
     System.out.println("not deleted");
}
```

I think that when I can't delete it is because it is still open somewhere in the Application.
But how can I can I close it, if I don't use the `FileInputStream` or the `BufferedReader`? Because if I use those classes, I can't see if the file exists. Or can I?

**Edit:** 
I just found my error. I was doing this:

```
XMLEventWriter eventWriter = outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
```

and then, closing just the `eventWriter` .

And I have to do this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
XMLEventWriter eventWriter = outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(fos);
```

and then:

```
    eventWriter.close();
    fos.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The file might be open by another process, you might not have sufficient rights to delete the file,...

**Edit:**

I also strongly recommend to use Automatic Resource Management wherever possible, to make sure your streams/ readers/ writers get  properly closed.

Comment: are you talking about the permissions? I checked that, and I have permission to write, read and execute.

Comment: Did you also check if another Process still holds a handle on the file?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use NIO2 Files.delete which throws an IOException that explains why the file could not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the BufferedReader class, you can't check for the existence, thats what the File class is for. You can just open/close the file using BufferedReader, and check with File. Here is an example:

```
String filePath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\temp.xml";
File f = new File(filePath);
if (f.exists())
{
   BufferedReader open = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));  // opens file
   open.write("blah");  //writes to file
   open.close();   // closes file
} else {
    System.out.println("File cannot be found");
}
```

Hopefully that helps you understand the situations a bit more!

Comment: A reader to write a file? Also the close-method call should be in a finally block.

Comment: Oh, I see the error. Ha, I meant FileWriter! but I know, it was just a simple example